# Transpose with unique columns in R

Tags: r, reshape, reshape2, tidyr

I have a data frame that looks similar to the below:

```
         X1    X2
 DocumentID 12345
     Check#  9876
 Investment Tran1
Investment$   200
 Investment Tran5
Investment$   100
 DocumentID 23456
     Check#  8765
 Investment Tran1
Investment$   100
 Investment Tran9
Investment$    50
 DocumentID 34567
     Check#  7654
 Investment Tran4
Investment$   300
 DocumentID 45678
     Check#  6543
 Investment Tran2
Investment$    10
 Investment Tran5
Investment$    20
 Investment Tran9
Investment$    70
```

Each Document ID will range in the # of Investments but I would like to reshape the data frame so that it is transposed (wide) per the DocumentID and has unique columns.

I'd like for the table to look as below:

```
DocumentID Check# Investment Investment$
     12345   9876      Tran1         200
     12345   9876      Tran5         100
     23456   8765      Tran1         100
     23456   8765      Tran9          50
     34567   7654      Tran4         300
     45678   6543      Tran2          10
     45678   6543      Tran5          20
     45678   6543      Tran9          70
```

So that the Document ID and Check# are repeated if there are more than 1 Investment in each Document ID.

Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 3):

Your data is poorly formed, as it lacks a unique ID for each set of key-value pairs, so the usual wide-to-long approaches likely won't work without some massaging. You can make a suitable column, then spread each row across the appropriate columns, then fill and filter:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

       # add row index so spreading will work
df %>% mutate(row = seq_along(X1)) %>% 
    # spread long to wide, shifting each value into the appropriate column, filling with NA
    spread(X1, X2, convert = TRUE) %>% 
    # get rid of row index
    select(-row) %>% 
    # fill in NA values for all but one column...
    fill(-`Investment$`) %>% 
    # ...so extra NAs in that column make extra rows easy to eliminate
    filter(complete.cases(.)) 

#   Check# DocumentID Investment Investment$
# 1   9876      12345      Tran1         200
# 2   9876      12345      Tran5         100
# 3   8765      23456      Tran1         100
# 4   8765      23456      Tran9          50
# 5   7654      34567      Tran4         300
# 6   6543      45678      Tran2          10
# 7   6543      45678      Tran5          20
# 8   6543      45678      Tran9          70
```

Answer (score 2):

```
cns.grp <- c('DocumentID','Check#');
ris.dat <- which(!df$X1%in%cns.grp);
cns.dat <- as.character(unique(df$X1[ris.dat]));
gs <- cumsum(df$X1==cns.grp[1L])[ris.dat[c(T,rep(F,length(cns.dat)-1L))]];
ar <- list(check.names=F);
with(unstack(df,X2~X1),do.call(data.frame,c(lapply(mget(cns.grp),`[`,gs),mget(cns.dat),ar)));
##   DocumentID Check# Investment Investment$
## 1      12345   9876      Tran1         200
## 2      12345   9876      Tran5         100
## 3      23456   8765      Tran1         100
## 4      23456   8765      Tran9          50
## 5      34567   7654      Tran4         300
## 6      45678   6543      Tran2          10
## 7      45678   6543      Tran5          20
## 8      45678   6543      Tran9          70
```

---

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(X1=structure(c(2L,1L,3L,4L,3L,4L,2L,1L,3L,4L,3L,4L,2L,1L,3L,4L,2L,1L,3L,
4L,3L,4L,3L,4L),.Label=c("Check#","DocumentID","Investment","Investment$"),class="factor"),
X2=structure(c(3L,15L,16L,5L,19L,2L,6L,14L,16L,2L,20L,10L,8L,13L,18L,7L,9L,11L,17L,1L,19L,
4L,20L,12L),.Label=c("10","100","12345","20","200","23456","300","34567","45678","50",
"6543","70","7654","8765","9876","Tran1","Tran2","Tran4","Tran5","Tran9"),class="factor")),
.Names=c("X1","X2"),row.names=c(NA,-24L),class="data.frame");
```

---

**Explanation**

```
cns.grp <- c('DocumentID','Check#');
```

Which rows of the input data.frame should be considered grouping markers is not derivable from the input data.frame itself; hence they must be hard-coded by the programmer. Thus I've assigned their `X1` values to `cns.grp`. This stands for *columns names of the grouping columns* (as they will serve as grouping columns in the output).

```
ris.dat <- which(!df$X1%in%cns.grp);
```

Given `cns.grp`, we can derive the *row indexes of the data columns* by finding the indexes of `X1` that are *not* equal to any of the values in `cns.grp`.

```
cns.dat <- as.character(unique(df$X1[ris.dat]));
```

Given `ris.dat`, we can derive the *column names of the data columns* by getting the unique `X1` values across the rows of `ris.dat`. I added an `as.character()` coercion to handle the possibility that the input data.frame has factor columns, as opposed to character columns.

```
gs <- cumsum(df$X1==cns.grp[1L])[ris.dat[c(T,rep(F,length(cns.dat)-1L))]];
```

In order to properly split the input data.frame along its groups, we must derive a grouping vector. Under the assumption that the first grouping column name indicates the start of a group (which is a reasonable assumption and seems to be the fundamental property of the input data.frame), we can use `cumsum()` incrementing on each occurrence of the first grouping column to produce a grouping vector correspondent to all rows of the input data.frame.

To jump ahead, we will use this grouping vector to expand the unique grouping value vectors received from `unstack()` along the unique data column instances. For example, for each `Investment` input row, we will index out the `DocumentID` element that corresponds to it. Hence we must filter the result of the `cumsum()` for just a single instance of each group per data subgroup. In other words, for each extent of length `length(cns.dat)`, we must get one and only one instance of that grouping index. This can be achieved by building a logical vector of that length with a single true value (doesn't matter which, since all grouping elements will be the same across the extent). We can build this logical vector with `c(T,rep(F,length(cns.dat)-1L))`, index out the selected row indexes from `ris.dat`, and then filter the `cumsum()` result on the selected row indexes. The result I store in `gs`.

```
ar <- list(check.names=F);
```

Here I just precompute additional arguments to the `data.frame()` call that will construct the output data.frame. Specifying `check.names=F` is necessary to protect the non-syntactic column names `Check#` and `Investment$` from normalization by `data.frame()`. You can optionally also specify `stringsAsFactors=F` to get character columns instead of the default factor columns.

```
with(unstack(df,X2~X1),do.call(data.frame,c(lapply(mget(cns.grp),`[`,gs),mget(cns.dat),ar)));
```

Finally, we can `unstack()` the data.frame to get each grouping column and data column as an independent list component, and execute an expression in the context of those vectors using `with()`.

We need only run a single call to `data.frame()` in this context to produce the required output. Basically, we need to combine the grouping columns, retrieved via `mget()` and properly expanded by `gs`, with the data columns, also retrieved via `mget()`, and include the precomputed additional arguments `ar` to produce the argument list to `data.frame()` that will be relayed by `do.call()`. The result is the required output.

---

**Benchmarking**

```
library(dplyr);
library(tidyr);
library(microbenchmark);

bgoldst <- function(df) { cns.grp <- c('DocumentID','Check#'); ris.dat <- which(!df$X1%in%cns.grp); cns.dat <- as.character(unique(df$X1[ris.dat])); gs <- cumsum(df$X1==cns.grp[1L])[ris.dat[c(T,rep(F,length(cns.dat)-1L))]]; ar <- list(check.names=F); with(unstack(df,X2~X1),do.call(data.frame,c(lapply(mget(cns.grp),`[`,gs),mget(cns.dat),ar))); };
alistaire <- function(df) { df %>% mutate(row = seq_along(X1)) %>% spread(X1, X2, convert = TRUE) %>% select(-row) %>% fill(-`Investment$`) %>% filter(complete.cases(.)); };
```

---

```
## OP's input
df <- structure(list(X1=structure(c(2L,1L,3L,4L,3L,4L,2L,1L,3L,4L,3L,4L,2L,1L,3L,4L,2L,1L,3L,
4L,3L,4L,3L,4L),.Label=c("Check#","DocumentID","Investment","Investment$"),class="factor"),
X2=structure(c(3L,15L,16L,5L,19L,2L,6L,14L,16L,2L,20L,10L,8L,13L,18L,7L,9L,11L,17L,1L,19L,
4L,20L,12L),.Label=c("10","100","12345","20","200","23456","300","34567","45678","50",
"6543","70","7654","8765","9876","Tran1","Tran2","Tran4","Tran5","Tran9"),class="factor")),
.Names=c("X1","X2"),row.names=c(NA,-24L),class="data.frame");

ex <- lapply(bgoldst(df),as.character); o <- names(ex);
identical(ex,lapply(alistaire(df)[o],as.character));
## [1] TRUE

microbenchmark(bgoldst(df),alistaire(df));
## Unit: microseconds
##           expr      min       lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
##    bgoldst(df)  794.151  862.362  917.3149  891.4415  934.2075  1488.659   100
##  alistaire(df) 2560.782 2677.318 3376.1405 2758.5720 2861.6365 53457.399   100
```

---

```
## scale test
set.seed(1L); NR <- 2L*1e5L; ND <- 8L; probG <- 0.25; X1 <- character(NR); cns.grp <- c('DocumentID','Check#'); NG <- length(cns.grp); cns.dat <- c(LETTERS[seq_len(ND-1L)],'Investment$'); X1[seq_len(NG)] <- cns.grp; i <- NG+1L; while (i<=NR-ND+1L) { if (runif(1L)<probG) { X1[seq(i,len=NG)] <- cns.grp; i <- i+NG; } else { X1[seq(i,len=ND)] <- cns.dat; i <- i+ND; }; }; if (i<=NR) { X1[seq(i,NR)] <- cns.grp; }; df <- data.frame(X1=X1,X2=seq_len(NR));

ex <- lapply(bgoldst(df),as.character); o <- names(ex);
identical(ex,lapply(alistaire(df)[o],as.character));
## [1] TRUE

microbenchmark(bgoldst(df),alistaire(df));
## Unit: milliseconds
##           expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq      max neval
##    bgoldst(df)  34.20791  35.90591  47.60333  44.02403  46.78709 119.4467   100
##  alistaire(df) 482.73097 540.84550 568.00577 557.26885 572.44025 741.9781   100
```

Comment: as always, very nice answer. I really enjoy your detailed explanations and thorough benchmarks.

Comment: Thanks @JosephWood, I really appreciate that.